# Chrome - Strange behavior of the console, when debugging Leaflet app

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, leaflet, geojson

The issue is this one: I'm getting different results at the Chorme's console when first loading the page with my Leaflet app code, and when I make a refresh.

At the first load, the console looks like this:
[image]

But in subsequent refreshes, it looks like this:

[image]

You can notice that in the first image, the object shown at line 309, has differents ID numbers compared to the second one (shows the content of a LayerGroup object, which has its own '_leaflet_id', and references to the '_leaflet_id's of its child layers).

Also, in the first image, it shows only the texts 'Object', 'M' and 'e' in the objects log, when collapsed. While in the second one, when collapsed, shows some of the object's content.

Some idea of what's going on?

The whole code is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="dSbDglIEK68iKVvD7JZexJ4CRPD65Ay5aIJ1GwxV">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Scripts -->


    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

<style>
    /* Definimos la altura minima del mapa */
    #mapid { min-height: 500px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:8000">
                    Laravel
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://github.com/nafiesl/laravel-leaflet-example" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" target="_blank">Source code</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:8000/our_outlets">Our Outlets</a></li>
                                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:8000/login">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:8000/register">Register</a>
                                                            </li>
                                            </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4 container">
            
<div class="card">
    
    <div class="card-body" id="mapid"></div>
</div>
        </main>
        <footer class="text-center fixed-bottom mb-2">
    The source code of this project is available on <a href="https://github.com/nafiesl/laravel-leaflet-example" target="_blank">github</a>.
</footer>
    </div>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>

<script>

    //Defino un objeto GeoJSON, que será parseado luego con los métodos de Leaflet.
    //En una aplicación mas compleja, obtendremos este objeto desde una API.
    //Sin embargo, para propósitos de prueba, lo definimos aquí directamente en nuestro documento.
    var GeoJSON  =  {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Prueba",
                    "address": "Casa de Lean",
                    "latitude": "-3.330076616628",
                    "longitude": "114.65040206909",
                    "creator_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2023-03-15T00:49:43.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-03-15T00:49:43.000000Z",
                    "coordinate": "-3.330076616628, 114.65040206909",
                    "map_popup_content": "<div class=\"my-2\"><strong>Outlet Name:</strong><br><a href=\"http://localhost:8000/outlets/1\" title=\"View Prueba Outlet detail\">Prueba</a></div><div class=\"my-2\"><strong>Coordinate:</strong><br>-3.330076616628, 114.65040206909</div>"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        "114.65040206909",
                        "-3.330076616628"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Casa de Gaby",
                    "address": "Liniers 557, Lomas del Mirador",
                    "latitude": "-34.66036884245",
                    "longitude": "-58.52985620498",
                    "creator_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2023-03-15T02:14:02.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-03-15T02:29:23.000000Z",
                    "coordinate": "-34.66036884245, -58.52985620498",
                    "map_popup_content": "<div class=\"my-2\"><strong>Outlet Name:</strong><br><a href=\"http://localhost:8000/outlets/2\" title=\"View Casa de Gaby Outlet detail\">Casa de Gaby</a></div><div class=\"my-2\"><strong>Coordinate:</strong><br>-34.66036884245, -58.52985620498</div>"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        "-58.52985620498",
                        "-34.66036884245"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    };    

    //Declaro una variable 'map' que contendrá el mapa instanciado por Leaflet.
    var map =               
        //Uso el objeto 'L' (de Leaflet), que contiene el método 'map', al cual le paso 'mapid',
        //correspondiente al atributo 'id' del <div> que lo contiene. Me instancia un objeto de tipo mapa.
        L.map('mapid')      
        //Este método 'setView', encadenado a 'map', lo utilizamos para centrar la vista predeterminada del mapa.
        .setView( 
            //En este caso, le pasamos un array con dos números, obtenidos de 'config/leaflet.php',
            //con las coordenadas donde queremos que se inicialize.
            [-34.61315,-58.37723],
            //Como segundo parámetro, desde el mismo archivo, le pasamos un número con el nivel de zoom que queremos.
            13
        );

    //Ahora tenemos un mapa navegable en el <div> correspondiente, pero sin ninguna visualización (todo gris).
    //Debemos agregarle una capa correspondiente, para poder visualizar un mapa desde alguna plataforma.
    //En este caso, será la de OpenstreetMap.
    //Lo hacemos con el método 'L.tileLayer'.
    //Le pasámos dos parámetros: un string y un objeto JSON con una sola propiedad (que contiene también un string).
    //Solo con propósitos de debug, nos guardamos el resultado de 'L.tileLayer' en una variable 'tile'
    var tile = L.tileLayer(
            'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}
        )
        //Aquí, encadenando el método 'addTo' al método 'L.tileLayer' a le agregamos la capa generada por el mismo
        //al mapa instanciado previamente, referenciado por la variable 'map'.
        .addTo(map); 
        
        var layer_cop;

    //Podría no haber utilizado el encadenamiento con 'addTo' y en cambio utilizar la sentencia:
    //map.addLayer(tile);
    //O bien:
    //tile.addTo(map);
    //Con el mismo resultado

    //¡Ojo! Esta linea no utiliza un método nativo de Leaflet, sinó que utiliza el plugin 'Leaflet.markercluster'.
    //Me instancia un grupo de marcadores
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();


        
    //En 'capa_marcadores', nos guardaremos lo que nos devuelva el método 'L.geoJSON'
    //Este método nos devolverá una capa GeoJSON, que es un objeto de tipo Layer,
    //apropiado para utilizar como capa en un mapa Leaflet.
    //Dicho objeto contendrá métodos en algunos de sus atributos,
    //y probablemente, referencias circulares en algunos otros.
    //Por lo tanto, NO se podrá codificar como un objeto JSON.
    var capa_marcadores =
        //Llamamos al método 'L.geoJSON' con dos parámetros:
        //-El objeto GeoJSON que nos devolvió la API
        //-Un objeto JavaScript, que contendrá las opciones en base a las cuales generará la capa.
        
        L.geoJSON(
            //Aquí le pasamos al método 'L.geoJSON', como primer parámetro,
            //el objeto GeoJSON devuelto por la API.
            //De esta forma, este método utilizará este objeto GeoJSON para obtener la información
            //a partir de la cual genera los elementos incluidos en la capa:
            GeoJSON
            
            ,
            //Aquí le pasamos al método 'L.geoJSON', como segundo parámetro, un objeto JavaScript,
            //en el cual incluiremos las opciones con las cuales queremos generar nuestra capa GeoJSON.
            //Podríamos tener muchas opciones codificadas aquí. En este caso, solo usamos 'pointToLayer'
            
            {
                //Dentro del objeto de opciones, definimos el atributo 'pointToLayer'.
                //Éste contendrá un método, que define la forma como que los puntos del objeto GeoJSON,
                //generan los elementos de la capa de Leaflet. Por defecto, generan marcadores.
                //En este caso, lo utilizamos para generar también marcadores, pero con un Popup asociado.
                pointToLayer: 
                    //Al definir la función correspondiente al método 'pointToLayer' desde este lugar
                    //con los parámetros 'geoJsonPoint' y 'latlng', los mismos adoptatán valores obtenidos
                    //a partir de el objeto GeoJSON que devolvió la API, el cual le habíamos pasado
                    //como primer parámetro al método 'L.geoJSON' (como 'response.data').
                    
                    //Esta función se ejecutará tantas veces como la cantidad de elementos en el
                    //array 'features', tengamos en el objeto GeoJSON devuelto por la API,
                    //el cual fue pasado como primer parámetro a 'L.geoJSON'.
                    function(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
                        //'geoJsonPoint', adoptará el valor de cada objeto correspondiente
                        //a cada elemento del array 'features' del objeto GeoJSON, de forma íntegra.
                        //Cada vez que se ejecute este método, este parámetro adoptará
                        //el valor de un elemento de dicho array ("Feature") diferente,
                        //hasta haberlo hecho con cada elemento existente en el.
                        console.log(geoJsonPoint);

                        //'latlng', contendrá un objeto con con solo dos propiedades: 'lat' y 'lng'.
                        //Dichas propiedades, contendrán la latitud y longitud, en forma de números,
                        //de cada punto en cada elemento del array 'features' en el objeto GeoJSON.
                        //Se descarta aquí, el resto de la información de cada "Feature".
                        console.log(latlng);

                        //En este 'return', establecemos como será el formato en el que se genera
                        //las capa de Leafleat, a partir de los puntos definidos en el objeto GeoJSON.
                        //En este caso, estos se encuentran representados por su latitud y longitud,
                        //contenidos en el parámetro 'latlng'.
                        //La capa se generará en forma de marcadores, los cuales tendrán un Popup asociado.
                        
                        var prueba=L.marker(latlng);
                        var prueba_cop=structuredClone(prueba);
                        
                        console.log("Contenido de 'prueba':");
                        console.log(prueba);
                        prueba.ejemplo="Saraza";
                        
                        console.log("Contenido de 'prueba_cop':");
                        console.log(prueba_cop);
                        console.log("Valor devuelto por 'L.marker(latlng)':");
                        console.log(L.marker(latlng));
                        
                        //Para ello, utilizamos el método 'L.marker', al cual le encadenaremos el método
                        //'bindPopup'.
                        //A 'L.marker', le pasamos el parámetro 'latlng', descripto mas arriba.

                        //Esta línea se ejecuta
                        //prueba.bindPopup("Hola");
                        
                        const callbackBind= function (layer) {
                                    //layer_cop={...layer};
                                    console.log("Contenido de 'layer':");
                                    console.log(layer);
                                    console.log(prueba);
                                    console.log(prueba==layer);
                                    //console.log(prueba);
                                    //console.log(layer.feature.properties.map_popup_content);
                                    //return "Hola";
                                    return layer.feature.properties.map_popup_content;
                                };
                        
                       return prueba.bindPopup(callbackBind);
                       return prueba;
                                /*
                        prueba.bindPopup(
                                function (layer) {
                                    //var layer_cop={...layer};
                                    console.log("Contenido de 'layer':");
                                    console.log(layer);
                                    //console.log("Contenido de 'layer_cop':");
                                    //console.log(layer_cop);
                                    console.log(layer.feature.properties.map_popup_content);
                                    return layer.feature.properties.map_popup_content;
                                }
                            );
                            */
                           /*
                        return L.marker(latlng)
                            //Al método 'bindPopup', que encadenamos luego del método 'marker', le
                            //pasamos una función callback como argumento, para asociar un Popup a cada
                            //marcador.
                            .bindPopup(
                                function (layer) {
                                    
                                    console.log("Contenido de 'layer':");
                                    console.log(layer);
                                    
                                    console.log("Contenido de 'map' y 'tile':");
                                    console.log(map);
                                    console.log(tile);
                                 
                                    return layer.feature.properties.map_popup_content;
                                }
                            );
                            */
                    }
            }
            


        );
    console.log("Contenido de marker y markers:");
    console.log(capa_marcadores);

    markers.addLayer(capa_marcadores);
    console.log(markers);

    //Podríamos tener, directamente:
    //map.addLayer(capa_marcadores);

    //Si dentro del 'then' del 'axios.get', hubieramos hecho
    //'map.addLayer(marker);' en vez de 'markers.addLayer(marker);',
    //no necesitaríamos la siguiente línea (nos saltearíamos una capa en la jerarquía):  
    map.addLayer(markers);
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!
Leandro

Comment: in addition to the full code can you paste sections of it where you suspect the unexpected behavior is arriving from?

Comment: @saylestyler I'm getting this from all my 'console.log's in the code.
Since these ones are located within all the code into the last <script> tags, I could just paste all that section, which would be pretty large too, but not so as the whole HTML document.